# How to split a column based on a string (when it exists) into a separate column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Event':['2018 Green Meeting','2018 Yellow Meeting','2018 Red Meeting',
'2017 Green Meeting','2017 Yellow Meeting','2017 Red Meeting',
'2016 Green Meeting','2016 Yellow Meeting','2016 Red Meeting',
'Blue Meeting','Purple Meeting','Green Meeting'],
'Count':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
})
```

I want to split the Event Column into two columns 'Year' and 'Event_Name' to get the following output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'Year':['2018','2018','2018',
'2017','2017','2017',
'2016','2016','2016',
'Blue Meeting','Purple Meeting','Green Meeting'],
'Event_Name':['Green Meeting','Yellow Meeting','Red Meeting',
'Green Meeting','Yellow Meeting','Red Meeting',
'Green Meeting','Yellow Meeting','Red Meeting',
'Blue Meeting','Purple Meeting','Green Meeting'],
'Count':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
})
```

When I try to use regex to do this. It dones not seem to be working. I am getting two columns 'Year' and 'Event_Name'. But the year is empty.

This is what I am using:

```
df[['Year','Event_Name']] = df['Event'].str.split(r'\d{4}',expand=True)
```

How do I get this to work correctly?

Comment: When you split on a pattern, that pattern is removed from the result. For instance, `'one and two and three'.split('and')` returns `['one ',' two ',' three']`; 'and' is removed from the result.

Answer (score 7):

Using `str.extract` with `fillna`

```
df['Year']=df.Event.str.extract('(\d+)').fillna(df.Event)
```

then We do `replace`

```
df['even_name']=df.Event.str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Comment: Hi Wen. I need to create two columns (1) Year (2) Event_Name. This ends up creating just one column Year. Moreover, for the last three rows where there is no year, it puts the Event_Name in the Year column.

Comment: `df['even_name']=df.Event.str.replace('\d+', '')` @AlhpaDelta also update in my answer

Answer (score 4):

#### `pandas.Series.str.findall`

```
s = df.Event.str.findall('(\d+|\D+)')

pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Count=df.Count,
    Event_Name=s.str[-1],
    Year=s.str[0]
))

    Count       Event_Name            Year
0       1    Green Meeting            2018
1       2   Yellow Meeting            2018
2       3      Red Meeting            2018
3       4    Green Meeting            2017
4       5   Yellow Meeting            2017
5       6      Red Meeting            2017
6       7    Green Meeting            2016
7       8   Yellow Meeting            2016
8       9      Red Meeting            2016
9      10     Blue Meeting    Blue Meeting
10     11   Purple Meeting  Purple Meeting
11     12    Green Meeting   Green Meeting
```

---

#### Non-regex

```
def f(x):
  a, b = x.split(None, 1)
  if a.isdecimal():
    return a, b
  else:
    return (x,)

s = df.Event.apply(f)

pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Count=df.Count,
    Event_Name=s.str[-1],
    Year=s.str[0]
))

    Count       Event_Name            Year
0       1    Green Meeting            2018
1       2   Yellow Meeting            2018
2       3      Red Meeting            2018
3       4    Green Meeting            2017
4       5   Yellow Meeting            2017
5       6      Red Meeting            2017
6       7    Green Meeting            2016
7       8   Yellow Meeting            2016
8       9      Red Meeting            2016
9      10     Blue Meeting    Blue Meeting
10     11   Purple Meeting  Purple Meeting
11     12    Green Meeting   Green Meeting
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a variation of this, and it worked completely. s = df['EventName'].str.findall('(\d{4})')
df['YearFromName'] = s.str[0]
t = df['EventName'].str.findall('(\D+)')
df['EventFromName'] = t.str[0]
df.to_csv(os.path.join(staging_area_folder,'df_w_year_3.csv'),index=False)

Comment: Thanks, is there any advantage to using the non-regex version vs the regex version?

Comment: I think non-regex is easier to read/understand/maintain.  There is also a [funny quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)

Comment: LOL Oh that quote it so true.

Answer (score 3):

Use `extractall`:

```
df[['Year','Event']] = df.Event.str.extractall('(\d{4})? ?(.+$)').reset_index('match', drop=True)
```

Output:

```
             Event  Count  Year
0    Green Meeting      1  2018
1   Yellow Meeting      2  2018
2      Red Meeting      3  2018
3    Green Meeting      4  2017
4   Yellow Meeting      5  2017
5      Red Meeting      6  2017
6    Green Meeting      7  2016
7   Yellow Meeting      8  2016
8      Red Meeting      9  2016
9     Blue Meeting     10   NaN
10  Purple Meeting     11   NaN
11   Green Meeting     12   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better, but is there a way to make it so that for the last three rows the Year Column is empty or has nan?

Comment: @AlhpaDelta Sure, get rid of that second line.  Like this.

Comment: could you help me understand what it does please? I under \d4 selects the 4 digits. But what does the rest of it do?

Comment: () is a group indicator and the ? after group means optional.  Optional space ' ?', then after that you have Group with . which means any character, + that appears more that once and $ means to the end of line.  So, the second group states get any characters till the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
def get_year(x):
    try:
        return int(x.split()[0])
    except:
        return None

def get_event_name(x):
    try:
        year = int(x.split()[0])
        return ' '.join(x.split()[1: ])
    except:
        return x

df['Year'] = df['Event'].apply(lambda x: get_year(x))
df['Event_Name'] = df['Event'].apply(lambda x: get_event_name(x))
df = df.drop(['Event', ], axis=1)
```

Comment: that is because "Blue Meeting" doesn't have a year in the example given, I assumed it's an error

Comment: No, its not an error. that is a feature of the data. Some rows have the year part, some dont.

Comment: Ok so do you want to include numbers for that case too?

Comment: No, there are no numbers. I want the output to be df2 (see in the original question). The year column will be empty or have nan for those rows